# Create OSx .app from c++ application

Tags: xcode, macos

I've created an OpenGL application using the Command Line Tool project template. 
Now the output project is obviously a unix executable.

My question is How can I convert this executable into a bundle .app? 
Have I to add another target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created a command line tool, it is just that, a command line tool. I don't know of any way to bundle it up into an application with ease.

If I were you, and you are going to start writing Mac OpenGL application, get set up with SFML. It greatly simplifies window creation, is cross platform and has a great community. Also, getting to the resource path in a mac .app bundle is a bit tricky and the templates they provide allow you to access any file with a call:

```
loadFile(resourcePath() + "filename.txt");
```

rather than having to keep track of everything. Plus, the whole resource path code is written in objective C which can be a pain for some C++ programmers.

The whole framework is pretty robust but maintains a simplistic style and its own namespace. Use what you want, don't use what you don't need. The latest version (still beta) 2.0, comes with Xcode templates. Just create a template and in build settings for your project, scroll to the bottom. You'll see SFML_LINK_DYLIBS_SUFFIX and it has a value of '-d'. Remove the '-d' and it should compile.

Then if you are distributing, add a copy files build phase and link the .dylib(s) that you used.

Comment: I can't understand if SFML can be used with GLUT or if it replace its functions with others. I mean, if I correctly understood: GLUT is used to simplify Windows creation and SFML too.

Comment: and... what you think about using NSGLView instead of GLUT and similar?

Comment: @MatterGoal If you're going to use SFML, there's not much point in using GLUT since SFML can do what GLUT does. The main advantage of SFML over NSOpenGLView for non-game applications is that SFML is cross-platform and NSOpenGLView is Mac-only. If you don't care about other operating systems, NSOpenGLView is fine to use.